# How to create fade animation in my case

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

I am trying to create a fade in and fade out feature for ng-show. I have read many posts but it seems like they were using old Angular version.

I have something like

```
<button ng-click="play()"></button>
<div id='wrapper' ng-show="animate" 
                  ng-animate="{show:'animate-show', hide:'animate-hide'}">
TEST HERE</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.animate = false;
$scope.play = function() {
    $scope.animate = true;   
}
```

CSS

```
.animate-show, .animate-hide {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 1s;
  -moz-transition:all linear 1s;
  -ms-transition:all linear 1s;
  -o-transition:all linear 1s;
  transition:all linear 1s;

}

.animate-show {
  opacity:0;
}

.animate-show.animate-show-active {
  opacity:1;
}

.animate-hide {
  opacity:1;
}

.animate-hide.animate-hide-active {
  opacity:0;
}
```

The above codes only show and hide element but doesn't provide animation. Does anyone have idea of how to animate it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add `angular-animate.js` file

add dependent module as

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

and modify the css

```
.animate-show,
.animate-hide {
   -webkit-transition:all linear 1s;
   -moz-transition:all linear 1s;
   -ms-transition:all linear 1s;
   -o-transition:all linear 1s;
   transition:all linear 1s;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-remove,
    .animate-hide.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block !important;
}

.animate-hide.ng-hide-add,
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
     opacity: 1;
     display: block !important;
 }
```

change `ng-animate` to `class`

```
<div id='wrapper' ng-show="animate" class="animate-show animate-hide">TEST HERE</div>
```

here is the Demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BCHK0fcMZHx4VVJZrgP8?p=preview)